# Caching some methods from a repository with a decorator pattern(?)

Tags: java, oop

I'm working on a project in java. This project doesn't use Spring or any other framework.

I have a class where I get some data from, lets call it a repository. Since this is a rather expensive call I'd like to cache the data. So I create an interface for that repository and build a decorator with a cacheable repository.

I have a repository interface like so

```
public interface ThingInterface {
    Map<Long, String> findById(long id);
    String findNameById(long id);
    String findConfigBySomeParameter(String param);
    Long findAnotherThingByAntoherParam(String param);
}
```

And the concrete repository that implements this interface

```
public class ThingRepository implements ThingInterface{
    @Override
    public Map<Long, String> findById(long id) {
        // get things for a database or wherever
    }

    @Override
    public String findNameById(long id) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public String findConfigBySomeParameter(String param) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Long findAnotherThingByAntoherParam(String param) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Now I want to cache some method results, but not all. I can implement a CachableRepository which will cache things or delegate to the non-cacheable repository in case of a miss.

```
public class CachableThingRepository implements ThingInterface{

    private ThingRepository thingRepository;
    private Cache cache;

    public CachableThingRepository(ThingRepository thingRepository, Cache cache) {
        this.thingRepository = thingRepository;
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<Long, String> findById(long id) {
        if(cache.has("some_key")) {
            return cache.get("some_key");
        }
        Map<Long, String> result = thingRepository.findById(id);
        cache.put("some_key", result);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String findNameById(long id) {
        if(cache.has("some_other_key")) {
            return cache.get("some_other_key");
        }
        String result = thingRepository.findNameById(id);
        cache.put("some_other_key", result);

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String findConfigBySomeParameter(String param) {
        return thingRepository.findConfigBySomeParameter(param);
    }

    @Override
    public Long findAnotherThingByAntoherParam(String param) {
        return thingRepository.findAnotherThingByAntoherParam(param);
    }
}
```

---

As I said, I want to cache some method results, **but not all**. So in this case, `findAnotherThingByAntoherParam` and `findConfigBySomeParameter` aren't cached. While the other 2 are.

`CachableThingRepository` isn't a good implementation. For starters the 2 non-cached methods shouldn't exist to begin with since they're not cached. From the outside, without looking at the code, one would assume that all methods are cached.

## **My question: how can I approach this?**

My solution is to simply remove the interface completely. Inject `ThingRepository` into `CachableThingRepository` and be left with something like this

```
public class CachableThingRepository{

    private ThingRepository thingRepository;
    private Cache cache;

    public CachableThingRepository(ThingRepository thingRepository, Cache cache) {
        this.thingRepository = thingRepository;
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    public Map<Long, String> findById(long id) {
        if(cache.has("some_key")) {
            return cache.get("some_key");
        }
        Map<Long, String> result = thingRepository.findById(id);
        cache.put(result);

        return result;
    }

    public String findNameById(long id) {
        if(cache.has("some_other_key")) {
            return cache.get("some_other_key");
        }
        String result = thingRepository.findNameById(id);
        cache.put(result);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Which in all fairness is considerably cleaner than the above. But I wouldn't mind hearing other peoples ideas on this matter.

Comment: _"For starters the 2 non-cached methods shouldn't exist to begin with since they're not cached"_  Why do you believe that?  Caching is an implementation/performance detail.  A user of this code should _never_ interact directly with a `CachableThingRepository`, only via the interface.  The concrete implementation should be acquired via a Factory or Builder object.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good if you want to differentiate the interfaces between the cached and the non-cached repositories. A facade is used to hide implementation details of a "bunch of classes", but it looks as you are more implementing different strategies to access data (strategy pattern).

So why is important for you to differentiate between cached and uncached methods? Or asked differently: Why is it important for the user of the `CachableThingRepository` to know which methods to *not* cache?

I would btw. just pass a `ThingInterface` to the `CachableThingRepository`, because that should be sufficient. If a user wants to ensure that uncached methods are used, then the user can use the `ThingRepository`, and for maybe cached access the user can use the `CachableThingRepository` - both have to be known as for the construction of the `CachableThingRepository` the uncached strategy has to be known.

Remember that even for the cached strategy not every call is served from the cache!

What you might want to add to the `CachableThingRepository` is some method to clear already cached values - individually per key or in global, or maybe automatically when you update stuff via the `CachableThingRepository`.

In general I would not recommend that you first define an interface but then you expose implementation details. You don't need the interface then... (but see my questions above, maybe there is a good reason to do that).

---

UPDATE: inspired by the discussions in the comment, you could also see the `Cache` implementation as a strategy and merge implementations of the current `ThingRepository` and `CachedThingRepository` into one class that always requires a `Cache` implementation.

Then implement a dummy cache, that doesn't do anything - and if you want uncached access, you provide that.

Take care that if you use a simple `null` value as "cache implementation" and react to that in your new `ThingRepository`, you put the caching strategy into your repository, which isn't following the strategy pattern and will make the class less maintainable.

But it could be a valid option if you desperately need some performance optimizations and profiling shows a bottleneck in the indirection there.

Comment: Indeed, the question you pose is a good one. The reason is that some data shouldn't be cached. For example: some users have some profile settings that rarely change(if ever). Those are fine to cache. But the same user can have some data that changes frequently, that is not fine to cache. So I agree with you thoughts on this: keep things separate and decide on a case by case basis. Either use `CachableThingRepository` or `ThingRepository`.

Comment: It seems that caching some results is an implementation detail, and not inherently relevant outside the class itself.  Calling it `CachableThingRepository` implies that caching is somehow critical to be able to use the class (other than the constructor).  But a user of the class doesn't (or shouldn't ) care.

Comment: Also a fair point @AndrewS what would you suggest in this case? Simply cache stuff directly in the `ThingRepository`?

Comment: yes - name as `ThingRepository`, and the caching of some results is just part of the implementation.

Comment: Not a terrible idea tbh.

Comment: I just added an idea for a different placing of the strategy into my answer.